# How to include device tree overlay into Raspberry Pi CM4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, yocto, device-tree

I would like to include UART3 and UART5 overlay to enable them, using Yocto. They are already delivered with the whole package (https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.10.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/uart3-overlay.dts) I added to my main image recipe lines:

```
RPI_KERNEL_DEVICETREE_OVERLAYS:append = " overlays/uart3-overlay.dtbo"
RPI_KERNEL_DEVICETREE_OVERLAYS:append = " overlays/uart5-overlay.dtbo"
```

I have also added .bbappend to enable them in /boot/config.txt `(file /meta-mylayer/recipes-bsp/bootfiles/rpi-config_%.bbappend):`

```
do_deploy:append() {
   echo "dtoverlay=uart3" >>"${DEPLOYDIR}/bootfiles/config.txt"
   echo "dtoverlay=uart5" >>"${DEPLOYDIR}/bootfiles/config.txt"
}
```

And I receive an error:

```
ERROR: _exec_cmd: install -m 0644 -D /home/jwz/work/build/tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi4-64/uart3-overlay.dtbo /home/jwz/work/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/adsb-debug-image/1.0-r0/tmp-wic/boot.1/overlays/uart3-overlay.dtbo returned '1' instead of 0
| output: install: cannot stat '/home/jwz/work/build/tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi4-64/uart3-overlay.dtbo': No such file or directory
```

I suppose that those overlays are not compiled, how can I include them into a compiling process?

Cheers

Comment: What recipe did fail ? `linux-raspberrypi` ?

Comment: Yes, it was because lack of uart3-overlay.dtbo files - but i found out that uart3-overlay.dtb exists. 

`RPI_KERNEL_DEVICETREE_OVERLAYS:append = " overlays/uart3-overlay.dtb"`
`RPI_KERNEL_DEVICETREE_OVERLAYS:append = " overlays/uart5-overlay.dtb"`
This added in local.conf compiles BUT removes /boot/overlays folder Instead of this, uart*-overlay.dtb are present in the /boot folder  . Serials still do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

Just add those lines into the local.conf inside the build folder.

```
/*HONISTER*/
RPI_KERNEL_DEVICETREE_OVERLAYS:append = " overlays/uart3.dtbo"
RPI_KERNEL_DEVICETREE_OVERLAYS:append = " overlays/uart5.dtbo"

/*DUNFELL*/
RPI_KERNEL_DEVICETREE_OVERLAYS_append = " overlays/uart3.dtbo"
RPI_KERNEL_DEVICETREE_OVERLAYS_append = " overlays/uart5.dtbo"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, you are a hero.